# Closed formula for number of $n$ distinct topologies

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

While studying some topoligies I asked myself how many distinct topologies exist on a set of $n$ points. It can be shown there is a relation to $T_0$ topologies and a formula for $n$ distinct topologies is given by $\sum_{k=0}^{n}S(n,k)T_0(k)$ where $S(n,k)$ denote the striling number of the second kind.

Are there also different formulas for the number of $n$ distinct topologies or is there even a closed formula? I mean there is a closed formula for the stirling number of the second so it might be able to find one for the topologies.

Comment: What $T_0(k)$ means?

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely hard problem:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements

Some topologies are related to partially ordered sets:http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/TCUPrintTalk.pdf